# Date Parsing Error "2016-06-17 15:42:20"

Tags: java

I am trying to parse a date string "2016-06-17 15:42:20" using `DateFormat.parse()` and I am getting and Exception reported:

```
java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: ""2016-06-17 15:42:20""
    at java.text.DateFormat.parse(DateFormat.java:357)
```

What is wrong with this Date string? I am using the format `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss` in my call.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: please paste the particular section of your code

Comment: It seems that you have some quotes in the date string. Remove them

Comment: Duplicates: [Parse Date String to Some Java Object](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8854780/642706) & [Parse a date from a string](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36441504/642706) & [How to extract date and time from a String Timestamp in java](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21796497/642706) & [How to split full date format in date and time - java](http://stackoverflow.com/q/37390405/642706) and more. Please search Stack Overflow before posting.

Answer (score 0):

note this:

```
java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: ""2016-06-17 15:42:20""
                                             ^-------------------^
```

Your date already has quotes around it, which aren't present in your format string. Probably you want `parse(date, "\"yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss\""` or similar.

Answer (score 0):

```
If input date String and from user format is different then java throws this error
```

[image]

make sure input date string format is same as the form user simple date format.

[image]